# What will be the output ? (VIsual C ++ in debug mode)

Tags: c++

File: sub.cpp

```
// The string to print
char str[] = "Hello World!\n";
```

File: main.cpp

```
/************************************************
 * print string -- Print a simple string. *
 ************************************************/
#include <iostream>

extern char *str; // The string to print

int main()
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I think the linker will not really be happy about `char *` vs `char[]`.

Comment: Why are you asking this question? Do you not have access to a compiler and want us to try your code for you? Or do you want someone to *explain* the output that you're getting? If so, please edit your question to include the actual output and the output you *expected* to see.

Comment: @Benoit's answer is correct - change char * to char[] and it outputs (on g++) (Benoit - I reckon write your comment as an anwer)

Comment: I can at least say that the output **will probably not** be "banana". For questions like this, it's usually easier to try yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The next time you find yourself somewhere wanting to know what a snippet of C++ code does, but without a compiler handy to test it for yourself, try [codepad.org](http://www.codepad.org/). Here's the output of your [sample code](http://codepad.org/oDXEfJDb):

> Line 9: error: conflicting declaration 'char* str'
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

As Benoit mentioned in a comment, you have declared `str` in one place as `char*` and in another as `char[]`. Those two types are incompatible, and that gives the linker a fit.

Changing the declarations to match will produce the following output, as probably expected:

> Hello World!

I'm not sure why you expect that the results will be different in Visual C++, much less in "Debug" mode.